# Which templates should be overridden in Symfony 2 error customization?

Tags: symfony, twig

From the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html):

> All of the error templates live inside TwigBundle. To override the
>   templates, we simply rely on the standard method for overriding
>   templates that live inside a bundle.

And:

> To see the full list of default error templates, see the
>   Resources/views/Exception directory of the TwigBundle.

Looking at the after-mentioned directory [i can find several files](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception). I'm interested in custom templates for 403, 404 and 500 errors, so i created `error.html.twig` (parent template) and `error403.html.twig`, `error404.html.twig` and `error500.html.twig` that extends from `'TwigBundle:Exception:error.html.twig'` (overridden by my custom parent template).

Is this correct? What happens if another kind of error or exception is thrown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is correct.

All other kind of exceptions will be caught by Kernel and error500.html.twig page will be rendered.

To test it, you can turn off your debug for a moment, by switching second parameter passed to  AppKerner constructor in app_dev.php

> $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);

Then you can

1. type wrong address to test 404 error page
2. throw any exception to test 500 error page

> throw new \Exception(); // test 500 error page

1. throw

> throw new
>   \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException();
>   or
>    throw new
>   \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException(403);
>   //to test 403 error page

Comment: Yes, it's linked in my question. Btw exception.html.twig template is never renderer, am i right?

Comment: sorry I missed it in your post.

Comment: I have just tested and exception.html.twig is rendered when you are in debug mode. Useful, I did not know about it before, so I was doing tricks with turn off/on debug

Comment: @gremo First off all thanks for posting this question. Can you describe it How you override all exception pages. I had do but not  success. Can you help me I want three pages error.html.twig , 403.html.twig, 404.html.twig.

Comment: @KunwarSiddharthSingh try to follow instructions from manual http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: @mrok Thanks for reply. Controller Show Action workes only after route url like www.symfony.com/about/hwsfhsbfh but In www.symfony.com/hfhdf not work show blank page on prod env and NOTHTTPFOUND Exception found in dev env , How can handle this ?

Comment: I've created a \App\Resources\TwigBundle\views\Exception\error404.html.twig custom page which works fine. But when i call an invalid url (no route found) it throws an NotFoundHttpException and then shows a blank page. In debug mode it shows a error but my custom 404-error page is not called.

Is this a bug?

Comment: In development mode (when you are using app_dev.php) you see NotFoundHttpException, Symfony displays your custom error/exception page in production mode (app.php)