# Customizing Symfony 2 Error Pages

Tags: symfony

I am trying to customize my 404, 500, and 503 error pages by following [Symfony's guide](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) but I am having problems trying to do so. I have created an empty `error404.html.twig` and placed it in `\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Resources\views\Exception`. When I view a non-existing page, I still see the default error page.

I've also been using `http://local.store.com/app_prod.php` to test but I get a plain (unstyled browser) 500 error page. I have created a `error500.html.twig` and placed it in `\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Resources\views\Exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mrok has answered my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640658/1179449).

Open `\web\app_dev.php` and modify:

`$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);` to

`$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);`.

Answer (score 4):

You file seems not to be in the right location.

To override error template, the right location is `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception`
You might have to create the directory and sub directory, because it is not present by default.

Comment: Which folder would I be creating? TwigBundle?

Comment: Yeah, and his subdirectory, in the Resources directory located in the app directory. Then you put yours files in the Exception directory.

Comment: I have placed my files in that directory, but it still isn't working.

Comment: To test, I have been going to `http://local.store.com/non-existing-path`, but I still see the default 404 page and not my customized 404 page.