# Creating custom error page in Symfony 2.5

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

I am working with Symfony 2.5.3 and I am trying to create the custom error page so for example if someone lands on a page or try to access a page that does not exist the `404` error message should appear within the theme of the site.

I understand that default `404` error page sits inside the `TwigBundle` that comes with symfony and looking at some other answers on this site people are [suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226092/customizing-symfony-2-error-pages) that in order to have the custom error page I need to copy them in directory `ROOT app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` so I copied over the `error.html.twig` and even created `error404.html.twig` but this does not work. I also looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640372/which-templates-should-be-overridden-in-symfony-2-error-customization) solution but still no luck.

I tried to access my development site via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.php/services` to check may be in production i will see the correct template but I dont, please note that i have cleared the cache before accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.php/services` and I still see the default error template that comes with Symfony

I will really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First double check this :

- Check if you're custom error template is in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` folder
- Then double check the name of you're custom error template if it is `error.html.twig` OR/AND `error404.html.twig`
- Then create the custom error/template that you want users to see
- You can see the custom error/page when you view the website via `app.php` which is a production environment.

Beetween each check

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

It should works now ;)

Another way to easily test your custom error template in dev mode is to use instead [WebfactoryExceptionsBundle](https://github.com/webfactory/exceptions-bundle) who provide a test controller for displaying your custom error page even when kernel.debug is set to true.

Comment: what is the point of using `app.php` when we need additional bundle to view what production looks like?

Comment: Symfony did this for the purpose of giving usfull information to the developper and just display error page to the end user. If you want to change this behaviour you'll need to change the default ExceptionController wich I don't advise. Either you use the specified Bundle or put kernel.debug to false to see your error pages as the end user :(

Comment: but I thought in `app.php` kernel.debug is off? why would it be on for `app.php`

Comment: It is. I tried on my symfony2 and I rememberd that you need in production mode to clear the cache in order to changes in your twig template. I edited the post. Does it work in you're environnement when you clear the cache

Comment: I am clearing my `app/cache` folder but that is not making any difference with i view a page that does not exist using `app.php` but i still see the default error page

Comment: Try to remove the error.html.twig in app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61347/discussion-between-isaac-and-baig).