# How to redirect 500 within an event listener?

Tags: symfony

I have a defined listener watching the `onKernelException` in which errors could occur.

```php
class SpecificExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        if ($exception instanceof SpecificExceptionToBeProcessed) {
            // ...
            if ($somethingWentWrong) {
                // here, redirect to the default/overriden Symfony error page
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

How do you redirect to the standard/customized error page in case of an error?

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640372/which-templates-should-be-overridden-in-symfony-2-error-customization/11640658#11640658

Comment: If your question is *"How to customize error pages?"*, you can follow @bartek link. If you need additionnal informations which are not described in the linked question, edit yours by adding the details you need. Or are you asking *"How to process a redirection when an exception occurs?"* (e.g: Redirect all errors to `/error`) Please clarify your post

Comment: Sorry @bartek but this is a different topic since it is happening within a listener processing a specific exception wich, in turn, can lead to unexpected errors. There, I need to redirect with a 500 to the standard/customized error page.

Comment: @Touki, I've added a piece of code.

Comment: Have you tried throwing (or re-throwing) an Exception in your listener? You might need some handling to avoid infinite loops, but I think that could work.

Comment: I think the best strategy is what @KalZekdor said, symfony has specific HTTP expections you can throw and the framework will pick it up,when thrown.

Comment: It depends on the priority given to the listener I think, nope? In my case, it seems like thrown exceptions are not caught by the framework since the error page does not show up. Hence the solution I propose below.

Comment: Yeah, was going to suggest crafting a Response object manually if throwing an exception didn't work. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might be interested, here's how it can be done:

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
// ...

class SpecificExceptionListener
{
    protected $templating;

    public function __construct(TwigEngine $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        if ($exception instanceof SpecificExceptionToBeProcessed) {
            // ...
            if ($somethingWentWrong) {
                // build response to display Symfony default error page
                // replace by your own template if needed
                $response = new Response();
                $response->setContent(
                    $this->templating->render('TwigBundle:Exception:error.html.twig')
                );

                $event->setResponse($response);

                return;
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```